# Data to Picture from AWT to JavaFX

Tags: arrays, image, javafx

So I have a application that uses AWT to display a result, using:

```
BufferedImage imagemap = new BufferedImage(map.getWidth(),
            map.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED,
            Imaging.ColorTables.get(this.color.getSelectedItem()));
    raster = imagemap.getRaster();

    data = map.getData();

    tolow = map.max * filter;
    max = map.max - tolow;

    for (int ix = 0; ix < data.length; ix++)
        data[ix] = data[ix] < tolow ? 0 : (data[ix] - tolow) / (max) * 255;

    raster.setPixels(0, 0, map.getWidth(), map.getHeight(), data);
```

Now I need to put out the same picture in JavaFX as UI Container I'm using a ImageView, and i suppose i will need to generate a WirtableImage to instert into the view. I have yet to find a way to generate the Image since it seems like I can't use a raster like in AWT. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is not changing often, you can create it as above and then use [`SwingFXUtils`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) to convert a `BufferedImage` to JavaFX's `Image` (actually it is a `WritableImage`, so further modifications are possible from the JavaFX side):

```
BufferedImage newImagemap = new BufferedImage(imagemap.getColorModel(), (WritableRaster) raster, true, new Hashtable());
WritableImage img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(newImagemap,null);
```

Comment: Thanks. The Image does change fairly often (readjusting a filter with a slider), but it doesn't seem to have a problem handling the changes.